# Why does python print statement 'end = \r' fail after many iterations?

Tags: printing, iteration, progress-bar, jupyter, python-3.7

I'm working on a jupyter notebook, and wish to print the status of an iteration. The status should overwrite the previous status update. If the iteration count is relatively low, lets say fewer than 1 million, the print statement overwrites the previous status correctly. However, when the iteration count is relatively high, the print statement begins to print to a new line.

Here is an example of the code working properly:

```
iterations = 101
for i in range(iterations):
    if i % int(iterations/25) == 0:
        print(f'{i}', end = '\r')
```

The code above properly prints i to the same line when the print statement is called. Here is an example of the code working incorrectly:

```
iterations = 10000001
for i in range(iterations):
    if i % int(iterations/25) == 0:
        print(f'{i}', end = '\r')
```

In this case the first and second time the print statement is called, it correctly overwrites the previous line with the print statement. After this, all other print calls are printed to a new line. Why does the behavior change? Is there any way to prevent the new line from being added?

EDIT: I ran the above code in the terminal from a .py file and the print function in both examples worked as expected, there were no lines added. It seems the behavior I've described is limited to running the code within a jupyter notebook. I'm still looking for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code on my machine and it works as intended, without newlines. May be a bug with your jupyter notebook version?
I'm using jupyter-lab 3.4.8 and python 3.10

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Since posting, I've run the code in the terminal (error was not replicated), .ipynb file in VScode (error was replicated), and in a jupyter notebook with access to more memory (error was not replicated). It does seem to be related to system and IDE.